# Using Matlab to change map projection of a geotiff map

Tags: matlab, dictionary, projection, geotiff

I loaded a map in GeoTiff format using geotiffread:

```
[A, cmap, refmat, bbox] = geotiffread('color_etopo1_ice_full.tif');
```

Since this map seems to be in one of the cylindrical projections, it means the continents are distorted. I want to change it so that I have a piece of a sphere instead, the way Matlab's Mapping Toolbox tutorials keep showing it can be done for shapefiles. I can't seem to get the same thing done with GeoTiff image and no tutorials handle that.

Can Matlab change projection of a GeoTiff image or should I use another software for it, then load the new image into Matlab so I can then plot my data on it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `gdalwarp` command line tool that comes with the `gdal` utilities.

The problem with reprojecting rasters is that you have to do an interpolation onto a new grid system with a new resolution - and this is generally not reversible, unlike vector data (shapefiles) where you can just reverse the coordinate transformation.

I suppose matlab has a 'system' function for calling command line utilities. Is this Windows or Linux or MacOS?

Comment: Righto. You can still get the gdal tools for Windows command line but I don't know how to call them from matlab...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to execute external, system commands (especially gdalwarp).
In case of Unix/Linux version, it might be needed to generate some symbolic links before you will be able to call GDAL, but it is still feasible.

I have different question.
Currently, I am processing GeoTIFF using Python (and importing some modules).
I have no Mapping Toolbox on Matlab, so I wonder if...
Is it feasible to do some calculations on rasters within MATLAB without mentioned toolbox? Is it reasonable? Will it give me any profits?